# How to know screen on time since last battery charge or reboot in Android?

Tags: android, screen

Is there any way to know the screen on time since last battery charge (or reboot) in Android?
This time is managed by the system and it show in Settings -> Battery,
but I need in my app.

Also, I know it's in Dumpsy's *batteryinfo*, but the generated information is about 28kb and I consider isn't useful to parse this file each time.

Comment: So, did you finally get the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcast receiver to estimate the time difference.

```
  ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
  ACTION_SCREEN_ON
  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
  ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
  ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
```

You will catch the time of booting the application,when screen goes off and back on again,also when device is connected to power and disconnected.Save the time and then find the difference according to your need.

Comment: this isn't a good solution, IMO. System is calculating this info, and i'm sure that exists a via to check it, but I don't known how :)

Comment: you told that in your question, you don't want to parse some heavy information.And till now i don't know anywhere else it would be found.So i gave you a workaround.You can at least calculale.

Comment: this is a workaround. But the problem is: you cannot assure that your app or service keeps running in background. So the only solution is to get it from System service, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [Getting Battery Information on Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html) and also look check the documentation here [Intent | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)

Getting the time of disconnected charger will be analogic with getting level percentage of battery.